# jquery checking current div on browser

Tags: jquery, html

Suppose I have a very long page composed of 10 divs:-

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="5"></div>
<div id="6"></div>
<div id="7"></div>
<div id="8"></div>
<div id="9"></div>
<div id="10"></div>
```

can I use jquery to check the current div that I am looking at within the 900px browser height?

Comment: Yes. Check the `offet().top` is > than 0, and the `offset().bottom + el.height()` is < `window.height` on `scroll` of the window.

Comment: could you give me a simple example? Thanks a lot!

Comment: simple answer, YES you can use. to get complex answer, show us what you tried in a fiddle.net or jsbin.com

Comment: Hi, you can try hover effect of mouse to find the current div. but it wont work if mouse is placed out of the browser.

Comment: this is up to your requirement, i.e. how do you want to check with `id`, some specific content or `index`. Please give your clarification on this.

Comment: Check out [Bootstrap - Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the offset from top of each div and the one that has a positive value is currently on your viewport. To smooth things a bit you can add to the calculations half of the height of the div. see the code bellow or check this jsbin : http://jsbin.com/gahoc/1/edit.

For more help please provide your complete html (and always remember ids shouldn't start with a number).

### HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div id="c1"></div>
    <div id="c2"></div>
    <div id="c3"></div>
    <div id="c4"></div>
    <div id="c5"></div>
    <div id="c6"></div>
    <div id="c7"></div>
    <div id="c8"></div>
    <div id="c9"></div>
    <div id="c10"></div>
  </div>
```

### CSS:

```
.container {
  width : 100%;
  height: 900px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin : 3px auto;
  width : 90%;
  height : 600px;
}
```

### JavaScript:

```
var $currentElement = null;

var highlightViewportElement =  function(){

  // reset previous element border
  if ($currentElement){
    $currentElement.css('border', '1px solid black');
  }
  // Iterate trough all the contained divs for their offset on top
  $('.container > div').each(function(){
    var $element = $(this);

    if (($element.offset().top + $element.height()/2)  >= 0){
      $currentElement = $element;
      return false;
    }
  });

  // Demo
  // a styling feedback
  $currentElement.css('border', '1px solid red');
  // outputing active element id
  $('#output').text($currentElement.attr('id'));
};
// Executing for the first time without the help of the scroll or touchmove event
highlightViewportElement();

$('.container').on('touchmove scroll',highlightViewportElement);
```